# Ubuntu 17.10 - Kerberos/SSSD AD User login only sometimes works

Tags: login, gdm, active-directory, kerberos, sssd

I am new here, so please advise me, if I did miss something about the rules here.

We are running a network of computers in a Windows Server 2016 AD domain.

In Ubuntu 16.04 we configured Ubuntu to allow for domain users to login via Kerberos and SSSD. A CIFS share is mounted at login as well via pam_mount.

This works flawlessly in Ubuntu 16.04. With the same smb.conf, sssd.conf and pam_mount.conf.xml in Ubuntu 17.10 however, login sometimes works and sometimes does not! Both via GUI and command line, as well as ssh.

It is really frustrating to pinpoint the error, as it does not occur regularly and login with AD credentials sometimes does work!

From what I was able to gather from the side of the DC, when Login on the Ubuntu 17.10 client fails, no kerberos ticket was requested by the client from the DC.

As I am not too familiar with SSSD, Kerberos and PAM, I was wondering, whether I was missing out on some new developments in these packages that make additional configuration necessary?

Where could I start to pinpoint the problem?

The error in the sssd_pam.log is:

```
(Thu Nov  2 18:57:00 2017) [sssd[pam]] [pam_dom_forwarder] (0x0100): pam_dp_send_req returned 0
(Thu Nov  2 18:57:00 2017) [sssd[pam]] [sss_dp_req_destructor] (0x0400): Deleting request: [0x5653aba02710:3:username@domain.name@domain.name]
(Thu Nov  2 18:57:00 2017) [sssd[pam]] [sbus_remove_timeout] (0x2000): 0x5653abdb83b0
(Thu Nov  2 18:57:00 2017) [sssd[pam]] [pam_dp_process_reply] (0x0200): received: [4 (System error)][domain.name]
```

The sssd.conf looks like this:

```
[sssd]
config_file_version = 2
services = nss,pam
domains = domain.name

[nss]

[pam]
debug_level = 8

[domain/domain.name]
debug_level = 8
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
auth_provider = ad
enumerate = true
cache_credentials = false
case_sensitive = false
override_homedir = /home/%u
default_shell = /bin/bash
create_homedir = true
remove_homedir = true
```

krb5.conf like this:

```
[libdefaults]
        default_realm = DOMAIN.NAME
        ticket_lifetime = 24h
        renew_lifetime = 7d

[realms]
        CYANOLAB = {
                kdc = server1.domain.name
                kdc = server2.domain.name
                admin_server = server1.domain.name
        }
```

And smb.conf like this:

```
[global]
workgroup = DOMAIN
client signing = yes
client use spnego = yes
realm = domain.name
security = ads
kerberos method = secrets and keytab
```

What I tried so far:

1. Enabled `cache_credentials` in the SSSD Configuration.
2. Reinstalled the entire system.
3. Fiddled with the common-* files.
4. Restarted all services (smbd,sssd, networking) manually.

All to no success.

I would really, really appreciate any tips, that could point me in the right direction to solving this mysterious (at least to me) problem.

Comment: *This works flawlessly in Ubuntu 16.04* so keep 16.04 which is a LTS release geared towards stability, professional use and supported until 2021 (17.10 is an interim release with only 9 months of support). Also 17.10 comes with huge changes and several issues should be expected because it has lots of things that need to be ironed out.

Comment: For most productive systems we will definately wait for the next LTS until we upgrade. But some people prefer to always have the current version, so I was testing that. I just thought, maybe I  commited an obvious mistake in my configuration, that would be easy to fix. So you think, this has nothing to do with my configuration and the system-side error will be ironed out in the next Ubuntu versions?

Comment: That will happen way before the next release :), via regular updates. BTW, that will be 18.04 **LTS** so you may want to test it even before its release because a) it will be awesome and b) it will soon be the *de facto* standard for production. Re: your actual question here, I'm afraid my networking knowledge isn't enough so I just commented in case you weren't aware of the different Ubuntu releases.